# Netsuite Hide Label Value on sublist items

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

How to hide title label value price on sublist item with suite script 1.0

**below is label :**

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to remove the sublist from the form.  Without the label (which is also the link to that sublist) you would never be able to access it.  IF that is the case you can do that by editing the form and removing that sublist from that specific form.